# nothing provides libcrypto.so.1.0.0(OPENSSL_1.0.0)(64bit)

Tags: php-openssl, sles, libcrypto

I ran over a sles 12 server and i got this issue when I try to install php7-openssl-7.2.13-155.1.x86_64.rpm :

```
zypper in ./php7-openssl-7.2.13-155.1.x86_64.rpm
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides libcrypto.so.1.0.0(OPENSSL_1.0.0)(64bit) needed by php7-openssl-7.2.13-155.1.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install php7-openssl-7.2.13-155.1.x86_64
 Solution 2: break php7-openssl-7.2.13-155.1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies
```

But when I check i got the lib:

```
ls /lib64/*crypto*
/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

But I don't know if it's well declared :

```
ldconfig -p | grep libcrypto.so
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (libc6) => /lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You appear to have the library but not from a package. What does `rpm -qf /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0` show?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got this answer :
`libopenssl1_0_0-1.0.2j-60.11.2.x86_64`

Comment: No idea what's wrong there. Solution 2 (install anyway) should work as you in fact do have the library. But the packaging system will probably be confused afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dratenik, I've installed the package ignoring the warning and it works !